# Jquery set cursor at the end of the text in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am working on my jquery script to remove the link by replace the text when I click on a button. I have got a problem with the cursor at the end of the text because it will move the cursor at the start of the text, example: when I click next to `2!`, it will move the cursor at the start before the `Video Here 1` when I try this:

```
selected_text = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer.wholeText;
$('#text_editor').html($('#text_editor').html().replace('<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Video Here 2!</a>', selected_text));
$('#text_editor').focus().val(selected_text);
```

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/su9dktrz/

What I want to achieve is when I click on the text "Video Here 1!", "Video Here 2!", "Video Here 3!" or whatever it is and when I click on a button to remove the hyperlink to replace it with a text, I want to move the cusor next to the text `2!` or whatever it is.

Can you please show me example how I can move the cursor next to the text `1!`, `2!`, `3!` or whatever it is in the contenteditable?

I have tried to find the answer on google but I couldn't find it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please confirm that when you `click` on a link, you want that link to be replaced with some text and then the cursor to appear at the end of that text?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clean this up for your browsers, I tested in FireFox.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ksd1gwp9/22/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function unlink(link) {
    var txt = link.text();
    var sp = $("<span>").html(txt);
    link.replaceWith(sp);
  }

  function getObjectFromCursor() {
    var obj, sel = window.getSelection() ? window.getSelection() : document.selection;
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    obj = $(range.startContainer.parentElement);
    console.log(obj, range);
    return obj;
  }

  $("#toolbar").on("click", "#toolbar_unlink", function() {
    var target = getObjectFromCursor();
    if (target.prop("nodeName") == "A") {
      unlink(target);
    }
  })
});
```

> The `Range` interface represents a fragment of a document that can contain nodes and parts of text nodes.

The range has nodes, for start and end of the selection, and these have references to parent elements. This is helpful for us to find the specific element the cursor is in or at. We can then target this element and replace it with plain text based on the content of the link.